# package dependency org.codehaus.jettison.json cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

Can anyone explain me what does the below error means? And how can I fix it?

```
The package dependency org.codehaus.jettison.json with the version greater than or equal to 1.3.0 required by bundle com.hosyt.astyanax.astyanax_1.0.13 cannot be resolved.
```

I am working with Maven and using Astyanax client with Cassandra.

Below is my `pom.xml file`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <!-- 1. Parent POM information Most of shared sections/configurations between 
        projects are inherited from parent pom. The shared sections are distributionManagement, 
        repositories, pluginRepositories, PluginManagement, Plugins 2. Switch this 
        to the project-specific aggregator pom -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.host.raptor</groupId>
        <artifactId>RaptorParent</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- POM Information about the Project -->
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.host.bulls.integ</groupId>
    <artifactId>BullsDAO</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!-- Packing Type is bundle for OSGI Library Bundle -->
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.host.astyanax</groupId>
            <artifactId>astyanax</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.host.bulls.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>BullsShared</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Build Configration -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Apache Felix Bundle Plugin - For Generation of Manifest after Compile 
                phase -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Configuration for generating the Manifest.mf -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>manifest</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <!-- Configuration for generating the Manifest.mf -->
                <configuration>
                    <manifestLocation>src/main/resources/META-INF</manifestLocation>
                    <!-- Manifest Headers which need to customized during manifest generation -->
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>com.host.bulls.integ.BullsDAO</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <!-- <Export-Package></Export-Package> -->
                        <Import-Package>*,
                            org.springframework.beans.factory;version="[3.0.5.RELEASE,4.0.0)",
                            org.springframework.beans.factory.config;version="[3.0.5.RELEASE,4.0.0)",
                            net.sf.cglib.core;version="[2.1.3,3.0.0)",
                            net.sf.cglib.proxy;version="[2.1.3,3.0.0)",
                            net.sf.cglib.reflect;version="[2.1.3,3.0.0)"
                        </Import-Package>
                        <!-- <X-Raptor-Pipeline-Handler></X-Raptor-Pipeline-Handler> -->
                        <!-- <X-Raptor-Initializer></X-Raptor-Initializer> -->
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Configuration of repositories for dependency resolution -->
    <repositories>
        <!-- Raptor Bundles Repository -->
        <!-- This is needed to locate the Raptor Parent project. Other repositories 
            come from the parent. -->

        <repository>
            <id>raptor.releases</id>
            <url>http://nxraptor/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <releases />
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <url>http://nxraptor/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <releases>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>thirdparty</id>
            <url>http://nxraptor/content/repositories/thirdparty/</url>
            <releases>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>host</id>
            <url>http://nxraptor.qa.host.com/content/repositories/thirdparty/</url>
            <releases />
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Central Repo</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>riptano</id>
            <name>riptano</name>
            <url>http://mvn.riptano.com/content/repositories/public</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means com.hosyt.astyanax.astyanax_1.0.13 depends on org.codehaus.jettison:jettison version 1.3.0 or greater but it's not found.Your pom includes version 1.3 but Maven determines 1.3 is older than 1.3.0. Try changing it into

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
    <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

(Assuming your project is compatible with 1.3.1)

Comment: Yeah I tried that as well. Still the same error I am getting. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @arsenal : if you are still getting the same error then how did you accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess (since I cannot check this because of the non-public artifacts): Move the jettison dependency before the astyanax dependency - because it seems to work for the cassandra-all dependency which you also exclude. To me it looks like Maven tries to resolve the transitive astyanax dependencies before knowing the later declaration.

Answer (score 0):

gradle dependency for Android

```
implementation ('com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.9') {
    exclude group: 'xmlpull', module: 'xmlpull'
}

implementation 'com.github.codehaus:jettison:jettison-1.3.7'
```